Display a bib(la)tex entry's source in document
I would like display the sources of a specific Bib(La)TeX entry in my document. Let's assume there is an entry with a key Lebowski1998, a call of MyCommand{Lebowski1998} should result in:
@Article{Lebowski1998,
  author    = {Lebowski, Jeffrey and Sobchak, Walter and Kerabatsos, Theodore Donald},
  journal   = {An open one},
  title     = {A catchy one},
  year      = {1998},
  doi       = {xx.xxxx/yyyyy.zzzzzzz},
  publisher = {One of the evil companies},
}

I tried a couple of approaches to declare <MyCommand> using biblatex itself, which was not successful. Then I played a bit with the package datatool in order to display the source, which did also not lead to the desired outcome.
My actual application is a citation hint, like done in this doument on pages 1 and 3. Has someone an idea how to realise it?

Well you would have to read in the .bib verbatim and, if there are other keys, look for the key and then parse until you find the closing brace. But that seems a lot of work. Why don't you simply copy & paste the source into a verbatim environment?

Thanks, for your input @UlrikeFischer - since it is a lot of work, as you said, I tried to find a kind of helper tool that cares about filtering my desired entry out of the bibliography. Copying it manually is something for a one time occasion, but I have quite frequent applications for this task and would like to automatise it. Especially since the information are present.

If the line number in the bib files does not change, you could use listings or minted to read code from the bib file. If you use lualatex, it shouldn't be too hard to dynamically query the line number.

well e.g. the listings package allows to read in files and to extract some lines or contents between some markers. You can also use biber to extract entries, but that requires to create a configuration file first.

listings, but also fancyverb allow to display the content of a file for a specified range of lines. This might be options, but I need to find a way to determine the corresponding lines. Lua, as suggested by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz might be an option, but I would prefer a method working not exclusively with LuaLaTeX.

The more I read, the more I tend to use fancyverb, its FancyVerbStopString option is a good way to find the end of the entry (doc, p. 14), but finding the start is still to be tackled somehow since the entry type may vary and one can specify only the entire line, not a substring to make use of the FancyVerbStartString/FancyVerbStopString options.

There are some tools intended for sorting and selecting from .bib files, such as BibTool. You can pipe the output of such a tool into your document. The tool will do the parsing of the .bib file for you, most likely with fewer bugs than something you come up with yourself. This needs the --shell-escape compilation flag because the tool is called externally.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\lstdefinestyle{bashfulStdout}{
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
columns=fullflexible,
keywords={},
showstringspaces=false
}
\begin{document}
The source of the entry Lebowski1998 is:
\bash[stdout]
bibtool -i references.bib -- preserve.key.case={on} -- 'select.by.string{$key "Lebowski1998"}'
\END
\end{document}

Result:

